# passing 3 parameters into a selenium ide command

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

Is it possible to pass 3 parameters into a selenium command via IDE? e.g.

```
Selenium.prototype.doSetList =function(array1,array2,storeAsVar)
{
   ....       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without making your own plug-in.
http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/plugins.html

There are only 2 parameters per command.  Just put the 2nd and 3rd into the 2nd and delimit them with a character that will never get used in the command.  I used a pipe character.

Example:

Command: setList
Target: valueOfArray1Argument
Value: valueOfArray2Argument|valueOfStoreAsVarArgument